# How to create tar.gz of each file of a particular type in single command?

Tags: find, tar, csh

I need to compress and decompress each of the files of a particular type say `*.html` in their respective location. 
For decompression, I used following command, it seemed to work for me:

```
find dir -name "*.html.tar.gz" -exec tar -xvzf {} \;
```

I'm able to see `*.htmp.tar.gz` in their respective directories.

For compression, I'm trying following command but it is not working as concatenation is not happening to the argument from find:

```
find dir -name "*.html" -exec tar -cvzf {}.tar.gz {} \;
```

Please suggest solution to this and let me know if solution to the decompression is not foolproof.

EDIT: Although I've right now used `gunzip` which do not require target name, but I'm wondering if `tar` is not possible at all. So, waiting for answer which solves the original problem.

EDIT: the requirement is to have a single command because I need to run it through `fork()` and `exec()` command from C function. So, I think piping is not possible.

EDIT: Also I'm looking for efficient way, because I want as little overhead as possible to the time taken for compression.

Comment: So you want to create an archive for each single file? Are you sure it's not okay for you to compress the html files directly?

Comment: Here type is just for an example. It could be anything depending upon the user and there might be lot of such files.which needs to be compressed and decompressed.
So, finding all such files and compressing them is the only solution. I know I can use loop here, but I want it in single command therefore I used "-exec"  option of find command.

Comment: Can be ok for you compress file directly? `-exec gzip {} `

Comment: Still: Why tar instead of compressing directly? You need to preserve file attributes or what?

Comment: @Philippos: Yes I need to preserve file attributes as well. I'm not sure if compressing directly will preserve that or not.

Comment: Neither am I. `man gzip` should know. (-:

Comment: @VivekAgrawal `gzip` will preserve ownership and file attributes if possible. If running `gzip` as the user that own the directories and files, or as `root`, then this is possible.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for the info, I will try gzip. I'll update if that works for me.

Comment: @all Thanks for your suggestion. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.html' -type f -exec sh -c '
   for file do tar czf "$file.tar.gz" "$file"; done' sh {} +
```

In C:

```
execlp("find", "find", ".", "-name", "*.html", "-type", "f", "-exec",
       "sh", "-c", "for file do tar czf \"$file.tar.gz\" \"$file\"; done",
       "sh", "{}", "+", 0);
```

To report failure or any archiving process to the caller, you could improve it to:

```
find . -name '*.html' -type f -exec sh -c '
  ok=true
  for file do
    tar czf "$file.tar.gz" "$file" || ok=false
  done
  "$ok"' sh {} +
```

With `-exec cmd {} +`, `find` exits with a non-zero exit status if any of the processes it spawns to execute the commands return with a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't you think Invoking shell would take lot of time since it will create whole environment before executing anything? I know I'm putting more conditions to my question but I wanted an efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Vivek, here with `{} +`, we're running one `sh` for every few thousand files (as much as can fit in the maximum number of arguments). The start-up time of that `sh` will be negligible compared to that of the thousands `tar` (and possibly thousands `gzip` if your `tar` invokes `gzip` for compressing the archive).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `xargs` to achieve this:

```
find "dir" -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I % tar zcpf %.tar.gz %
```

It handles almost all special characters in filenames.

Comment: This is really informative. Thanks for this info. Actually my requirement was to run single command through fork and exec within C function. So piping will not work for me, I think. BTW, I was trying to upvote your answer but unable to do so because of less reputation. :(

Comment: Can we convert this in a single command?

Comment: If you want to handle files with space in their name, then no. But you can always put it into a file, save it as "something.sh" and call it from wherever you want.